# LINQ order by and then by

Tags: c#, sql, linq

my code :

```
  var list3 = _ItemForCheckService
    .GetBy(x => x.Status != Status.Deleted)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Approver != null || x.Approver2 != null)
    .ThenBy(x => x.ModifiedDate)
    .ToList();
```

> approver=guid approver2=guid modifieddate=datetime

if any of my list item has approver or approver2 value (Not null) it must be on top of my list. 
if none of items has value of approver or approver2 they should be listed by their modified date (oldest is first).

in my code, it doesn't work.

Thanks.

**Edit** : I tried `OrderByDesc` still i don't see the

> grouped approver or approver2 results

on the *top* or *bottom* of my page..they didn't grouped together

Comment: since `false < true` you, probably, want `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Approver != null || x.Approver2 != null)`

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What is your data?  What are your results?  What results were you expecting?  Why?  Are you confusing `false` with `null`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: Your comment didn't work... ;-) "Didn't work" is not much of a problem description. Note that we don't have the problem, and we don't see your problem. You have a problem, you see the problem. We would need you to tell us to be able to help you. It is in your hands whether we can help you...

Comment: sorry i edited original post

Comment: I suggest you add an example data for whatever _ItemForCheckService.GetBy(...) returns/produces to your question. Based on the explanation of the results you desire, OrderByDescending should do the trick. Something in the description of your question does not seem to add up. Somewhere there seems to be a confusion in your question...

Comment: *"on top or bottom of my page"* - What "page"?  The code you're showing doesn't have a "page".  And any sorting or modifications of data could exist between the code you're showing us and this "page" to which you allude.  Put aside your "page" for a moment and examine the contents of this `list3` variable.  What specifically is your source data?  What specifically does this variable contain?  What did you expect it to contain?  Why?

Comment: Since `Guid` is `struct` it *can't* be `null`, so if `approver` and `approver2` are of type `Guid` ("approver=guid approver2=guid modifieddate=datetime") then `x => x.Approver != null || x.Approver2 != null` will be `true`, rain or shine

Answer (score 1):

Without test data to pin down the error, a crystal ball required. You may have several issues here:

1. Since `false < true` you may want to use `.OrderByDescending(...)` instead of `.OrderBy()`
2. Since `Guid` is `struct` it *can't be* `null` (but can be compared with `null` to return `true`)
3. You may want to put on top items which have *both* `Approver` and `Approver2` then items with *single* approver, then with *none*.

Code (assuming `Approver` as well as `Approver2` are of type `Guid`):

```
var list3 = _ItemForCheckService
   .GetBy(x => x.Status != Status.Deleted)
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Approver != default(Guid) || x.Approver2 != default(Guid))
   .ThenBy(x => x.ModifiedDate)
   .ToList();
```

or if we want to implement point `3.`:

```
var list3 = _ItemForCheckService
   .GetBy(x => x.Status != Status.Deleted)
   .OrderBy(x => (x.Approver != default(Guid) ? 0 : 1) + 
                 (x.Approver2 != default(Guid) ? 0 : 1))
   .ThenBy(x => x.ModifiedDate)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: sorry, i explain better now . i want my not null approver or not null approver2 list items grouped together on top of the list. The rest will be grouped together null approver and null aproover2 .

Comment: @hohoholololo: do you want sorted or grouped (i.e. `2` groups - approved by at least either `Approver` and `Approver2` and not approved). What's `Approver` and `Approver2` types (some class or `Guid`)?

Comment: i want grouped first later sorted.